# How to pass an object in android if the object has a non primitive property (parcelable)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

I have this object "Table" (as in restaurant table) which implements parcel able but has an object property "Bill". I need to pass this object to another activity but I can't write the object like I do with string or int how do I implement the writetoparcel methods and such?

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way is for the Bill object to also implement Parcelable.

A nastier way is if you can store enough of the data about Bill to recreate it when Table is unparceled.  This is discouraged though-  it requires you to know a lot about the implementation of the Bill object in the Table class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make type of `Bill` property implements `Parcelable` and use method `writeParcelable()`.